# register statement - Asterisk Realtime

Tags: asterisk

HI, the register statement in sip.conf allows your Asterisk server to register with a provider. Is it possible to put this register statement into a realtime database and update in realtime. Using Asterisk 1.6.2.8

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll want to refer to the following documentation:
[voip-info.org: Asterisk RealTime Sip](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime+Sip)

Be sure to scroll to the bottom of the page. There's an example that you can go off of. You'll need to go through each of the table columns to see what is applicable for your host configuration, but I imagine that these columns will be of particular interest:

- context
- deny
- permit
- secret
- host
- qualify
- disallow
- allow
- username

Hope this helps!